# Django pre-populate form fields with api data

Tags: django, forms

I'm attempting to populate a form field with data gathered from a third party api from a user's search. I'd like the form data to be saved into the user's database when they click 'add artist'. Currently just trying to pass the name of the artist searched.

```
    <form action="{% url 'add_artist' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ artist.name }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="image" value="{{ artist.image_url }}">
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add Artist">
</form>
```

Because I'm not using a CBV I'm having difficulty saving to the database because I don't have the built in form/model relationship. I was wondering if there's a way to use form methods on non CBV form submission within Django. Ideally the view function would look something like this:

```
def add_artist(request): 
  form = ArtistForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
   new_artist = form.save(commit=False)
   new_artist.user = request.user
   new_artist.save()
  return render(request, 'artists/index.html', {
'artists': new_artist 
})
```

Here is the model:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={'artist_id': self.id})
```

Here is the api call:

```
def show(request):
    searched_artist = request.POST['name_field']
    appKey = os.environ['APP_ID']
    req = requests.get(f"http://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/{searched_artist}?app_id={appKey}")
    req = req.json()
    events = requests.get(f"http://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/{searched_artist}/events?app_id={appKey}")
    events = events.json()
    return render(request, 'detail.html',{
      'artist': req,
      'events': events,
    })
```

Here is my forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Artist, Event

class ArtistForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
   model = Artist
   fields = ['name', 'image']
```

Comment: How are you getting the data from the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question properly, you want the frontend to display the artist submitted with the form. If so, something like this. (And yes, you can use form.is_valid() outside of class based views ...

```
def add_artist(request, artist_id): 
         form = ArtistForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
         name = None #Or call to database (Artist.objects.filter(id=artist_id) if you want the form populated before submission
         if form.is_valid():
              user = request.user
              name = form.cleaned_data.get("name")
              foo = Artist(user = user, name=name)
              foo.save()
         return render(request, 'artists/index.html', {'artists': name})
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the standard unnamed html form I provide in the template?

Comment: No, you have to  name it, or the backend won't be able to match it for verification ... <form name ='' NameOfYourForm">

Comment: I keep getting 'NameOfYourForm' is not defined, I specified the form name in the template but it doesn't seem to be picking it up

Comment: post your forms.py

Comment: I'm thinking that it must have something to do with the hidden form fields I'm passing not being able to save to the form class fields, getting a ValueError

Comment: I don't think that's it ... A simpe check would be to try it w/o the hidden, but I still think the packet sends the same upon submit ...Also, try to print(name)  under the if form.is_valid() ... see what it says ...

Comment: 'name is not defined'

Comment: So, the form is verifying as valid; it's just not picking up the data from the name field?

Comment: figured it out, it was a problem with the model not accepting the form data type, thanks for the help Jay!